# What is the difference between a Body Check and Woman's Body Check?

Tags: officiating, terminology, ice-hockey, olympics

This image is from the Sochi Winter Olympics:

[image]

Why is *Women Body Checking* different from a regular *Body Check*?

I mean, pretty sure not every penalty was preceded by Women's in the match (like *Women High Sticking* or *Women Hooking*) so why is Body Checking seemingly in a different category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, body checking in women's hockey is prohibited while body checking in men's hockey is not.

In essence, while the act of body checking is self-explanatory, a Woman's Body Check denotes an illegal act while a Body Check denotes the act itself, which is common in men's hockey.

Rule 604 in USA Hockey states:

> Body checking is prohibited in the 12 & under youth age classification
>   and below and **all** Girls’/Women’s age classifications.
>
> Body checking is also prohibited in all non-check Adult
>   classifications.
>
> A local governing body may prohibit body checking in any
>   classification.

Comment: Ah ok so thats why theres a difference. I didn't put it together that there is checking in both, but it's a penalty only in the womens event.